# npm osmosis. How i can get attr of element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio, osmosis

**part HTML code of page**

```
<div name="price" class="detail-price-test">
  <meta itemprop="price" content="3303">
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="test">
  <span id="price_label">3 303</span><span class="detail-price-test-sign" id="price_label_sign"> eur</span>
  <script>
    if (price_json.price != '0') {
    var price_container = document.getElementById('price_container'),
    price_cheaper_selector = 'detail-price-cheaper';
    document.getElementById('price_label').innerHTML = price_json.price_formatted;
    document.getElementById('price_label_sign').innerHTML = "&thinsp;eur";
    if (parseFloat(price_json.old_price) >
    parseFloat(price_json.price) &&
    price_container &&
    !price_container.hasClass(price_cheaper_selector)
    ) {
    price_container.addClass(price_cheaper_selector);
    }
    }
  </script>
  <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
</div>
```

**1) First question:** How i can extract attr content with value 3303 from meta itemprop="price" ?
OR with osmosis, it is impossible to make?

**2) Second question:** Why i cant get value 3 303 in this `<span id="price_label">3 303</span>`

```
osmosis
.get('myURL.com')
.find('div.detail-price-test span#price_label') //or div.detail-price-test span[id=price_label]
.set('test')
.data(console.log);
```

Result in cosole: test: ''

Maybe the problem in `JavaScript` script and osmosis can't work with this?

Comment: I also checked in cheerio. Dont work too on this element <span id="price_label">3 303</span>

Comment: Hello John, please see my answer. You need to update your selector.

Answer (score 0):

In Cheerio it's:

```
$('[itemprop="price"]').attr('content')
```

In osmosis? No idea, I've never heard of it.

Comment: thx, but in cheerio i already know about attr(), i need learn about this posibility in osmosis

Comment: If I were you I would remove osmosis a a dependency for your project. This is some sort of hobby library.

Comment: Don't underestimate Osmosis. Yes it has pros and cons but definitely very useful for crawling. No library out there can crawl faster than what osmosis can do. It has its purpose. I used request-cheerio back then. I tried selenium, puppeteer, nightmare, phantomjs as well. But I always go back to osmosis, whenever I need something scraped quick.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect.

First question answer:
The selector should be: `'meta[itemprop="price"]@content'`
You can do something like this:

```
osmosis
.get('myURL.com')
.find('meta[itemprop="price"]@content')
.set('price')
.data(console.log) // {price : 3303}
```

Second question answer: 
The correct selector is either

1. `'div.detail-price-test > span#price_label'`
2. `'span#price_label'`
3. `'#price_label'`

do something like:

```
osmosis
.get('myURL.com')
.find('div.detail-price-test > span#price_label')
.set('test')
.data(console.log); // {test : 3...}
```